# How to take hourly screenshots on an iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad, automation

Does the iPad have the ability to take screenshots every X amount of time? How can I make the iPad take screenshots automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the automation feature in the Shortcuts App to take a screenshot at a specific time. It supports daily repeats, but you‘ll need to create an automation for each hour you want to have a record of.